# How to evaluate the limit : $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^n}{(n!)^2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I know the result is quite obvious using the stirling fomula,but how to use more plain method to evaluate this limit? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n<n!<e\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n$

Comment: $\prod\frac n{k(n-k)}$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2727526/compute-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-fracnnn2?noredirect=1